# PCSX2 displays black screen

Tags: gaming, emulator, ps2

I have downloaded PCSX2 version 1.0.0 for Windows from the PCSX2 team's official site, http://pcsx2.net/. I own a PS2 and I have installed PCSX2 with a bios. I want to play the PS2 game "DragonBall Z - Budokai 3", but I am experiencing a black screen when I try to play it. My configurations are standard.

At startup pcsx2-r5350.exe creates a program log. It says:

```
PCSX2 1.0.0.r5350  - compiled on Aug  1 2012
Savestate version: 0x9a080000

Host Machine Init:
    Operating System =  Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1 (build 7601), 64-bit
    Physical RAM     =  6026 MB
    CPU name         =  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3740QM CPU @ 2.70GHz
    Vendor/Model     =  GenuineIntel (stepping 09)
    CPU speed        =  2.693 ghz (8 logical threads)
    x86PType         =  Standard OEM
    x86Flags         =  bfebfbff 7fbae3ff
    x86EFlags        =  28100000

x86 Features Detected:
    MMX.. SSE.. SSE2.. SSE3.. SSSE3.. SSE4.1.. SSE4.2.. AVX

Reserving memory for recompilers...

Loading plugins...
    Binding   GS: C:\Program Files (x86)\PCSX2 1.0.0\Plugins\gsdx32-avx-r5350.dll 
Windows 6.1.7601 (Service Pack 1 1.0)
NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M  (9.18.13.697)
    Binding  PAD: C:\Program Files (x86)\PCSX2 1.0.0\Plugins\lilypad-r5350.dll 
    Binding SPU2: C:\Program Files (x86)\PCSX2 1.0.0\Plugins\spu2-x-r5350.dll 
    Binding CDVD: C:\Program Files (x86)\PCSX2 1.0.0\Plugins\cdvdGigaherz.dll 
    Binding  USB: C:\Program Files (x86)\PCSX2 1.0.0\Plugins\USBnull.dll 
    Binding   FW: C:\Program Files (x86)\PCSX2 1.0.0\Plugins\FWnull.dll 
    Binding DEV9: C:\Program Files (x86)\PCSX2 1.0.0\Plugins\DEV9null.dll 
Plugins loaded successfully.

(GameDB) 9640 games on record (loaded in 371ms)
```

I have used ImgBurn, http://www.imgburn.com/, to create an .iso file so I can play the game without the disc. When I use "Boot CDVD (full)" the screen goes black and the intro sound plays. "Boot CDVD (fast)" makes just the screen go black. The program log, "Boot CDVD (full)", disc, says:

```
HLE Notice: ELF does not have a path.


Initializing plugins...
    Init GS
Windows 6.1.7601 (Service Pack 1 1.0)
NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M  (9.18.13.697)
    Init PAD
    Init SPU2
    Init CDVD
    Init USB
    Init FW
    Init DEV9
Plugins initialized successfully.

Opening plugins...
    Opening GS
    Opening PAD
    Opening SPU2
    Opening CDVD
 * CDVD: Opening drive '\\.\D:'...
 * CDVD: IO thread started...
 * CDVD: Disk Type: Double-Layer DVD
 * CDVD Disk Open: DVD, Single layer or unknown:
 * * Track 1: Data (Mode 2) (2274320 sectors)
    Opening USB
    Opening FW
    Opening DEV9
McdSlot 0: C:\Users\Kapper\Documents\PCSX2\memcards\Mcd001.ps2
McdSlot 1: C:\Users\Kapper\Documents\PCSX2\memcards\Mcd002.ps2
Plugins opened successfully.
EE/iR5900-32 Recompiler Reset
    Bios Found: Europe  v02.00(14/06/2004)  Console
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to NTSC.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 59.94 fps
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to PAL.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 50.00 fps
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to NTSC.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 59.94 fps
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to PAL.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 50.00 fps
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to NTSC.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 59.94 fps
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to PAL.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 50.00 fps
(SYSTEM.CNF) Detected PS2 Disc = cdrom0:\SLES_533.46;1
(SYSTEM.CNF) Software version = 1.00
(SYSTEM.CNF) Disc region type = PAL
ELF (cdrom0:\SLES_533.46;1) Game CRC = 0x4E0D7BDE, EntryPoint = 0x00100008
(SYSTEM.CNF) Detected PS2 Disc = cdrom0:\SLES_533.46;1
(SYSTEM.CNF) Software version = 1.00
(SYSTEM.CNF) Disc region type = PAL
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to NTSC.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 59.94 fps
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to PAL.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 50.00 fps
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to NTSC.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 59.94 fps
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to PAL.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 50.00 fps
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to NTSC.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 59.94 fps
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to PAL.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 50.00 fps
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to NTSC.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 59.94 fps
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to PAL.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 50.00 fps
(SYSTEM.CNF) Detected PS2 Disc = cdrom0:\SLES_533.46;1
(SYSTEM.CNF) Software version = 1.00
(SYSTEM.CNF) Disc region type = PAL
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to NTSC.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 59.94 fps
(UpdateVSyncRate) Mode Changed to PAL.
(UpdateVSyncRate) FPS Limit Changed : 50.00 fps
```

Since the problem can be the video, I have tried to change the renderer,

```
"Config" > "Video (GS)" > "Plugin Settings..." > "Renderer:",
```

from the default, Direct3D9 (Software), to all of the other options, but nothing helps.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your BIOS PAL or NTSC?

Comment: The game is bought in Europe, Denmark, so I suppose it may work best with PAL. I own a PlayStation, which is bought in Denmark too, but I downloaded a BIOS for the emulator, because I don't really know how to get it from the PlayStation 2 itself. The folder consists of many files. I don't know if they're the right ones. Do you need a screenshot of my folder?

Comment: [Here](http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/5739/folderbios.png) is information about the BIOS, I use.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was similar, but it was with a different game: *Jak X Combat Racing*. This game has a lot of bugs on PCSX2, but I solved the black screen problem with this steps:

1. Check if your Jak X Combat Racing is **PAL** or **NTSC** version.
2. Download [THIS](https://forums.pcsx2.net/attachment.php?aid=48708) *.npach* file for **PAL** or [THIS](https://forums.pcsx2.net/attachment.php?aid=48756) for **NTSC**.
3. Put the files on *cheats folder* (Documents -> PCSX2 -> cheats)
4. Open PCSX2 and *enable cheats* (System -> Enable cheats)
5. Open your game and enjoy!

All credits go to this forum: https://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-Jak-X-Patched-NTSC-and-PAL

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the problem is with the *PCSX2* adapter you are using. Try to test all the adapters and check if it works.

You can change your adapter in: **Configuration > Video > Plug-in Configuration > Adapter**